# Compare two columns and highlight when found -

Tags: excel

Excel compare two columns and highlight when found

I have tried the various suggestions using conditional formatting however, when I compare 1,000 lines of Data in column A to 8,000 lines of Data in column N, **some of my cells will come back formatted (showing a match) but other cell that contain the identical number in the 2 columns do not format as showing a match**.

I'm comparing Part numbers and some of the numbers do contain letters; however, I have formatted both columns as a "General" format, thinking that one columns part number is not formatted the same as the other column's part number.

No matter which example I use, they both come back with an identical part numbers not being found in column "N", but the part # is actually in both column A & N.  I test by doing a Cntrl Find and the part # is found in both columns, but will not come back formatted identifying it as such.  I've tried:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$N:$N,1,FALSE)))
```

and

```
=COUNTIF($N:$N,A1)
```

Comment: Extra spaces, or other characters you cannot see?

Answer (score 0):

Please try selecting ColumnN, Use a formula to determine which cells to format / Format values where this formula is true:

```
=--COUNTIF(A:A,N1)
```